# can't delete glassfish directory in docker container

Tags: linux, docker, glassfish-4.1

Because of a known glassfish bug I tried to remove the glassfish/domains/domain1/generated folder. We are running it in a docker container and it works well but somehow I can't delete these files.
rm -rf or rm -r generated/* works perfectly on my local installation. Even when I copy a new glassfish4.1 into the container I cant delete the files.

Error message:

```
root@d032ccb9df70:/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1# rm -r generated/*
rm: cannot remove 'generated/ejb': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove 'generated/jsp': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove 'generated/policy': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove 'generated/xml': Directory not empty
```

it seems like they are locked but I have no clue why. When I try to remove the whole glassfish, the path to the mentioned files stays untouched and the rest is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like its a known docker-bug: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1672

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see if `lsof` is available in the container and then take a specific file and do a `lsof <filename>` to see what process, if any, has locked those processes.

Comment: no results from `lsof generated/` ... It seems like something in the container is broken

Comment: lets do some more trouble shooting, start the container, get the PID of the container by inspecting the container. Go to /proc/pid/root/<ur path to generated folder>. Do a find . -print0 | xargs -0 lsof. Lets see if it returns anything for any of the files under the generated folder.

Comment: thanks for your help so far Yogesh_D. I did what u said and got the following output back: root@adkre:/proc/3487/root/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated# find . -print0 | xargs -0 lsof
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
bash    2926 root  cwd    DIR   0,43     4096  114 .
xargs   3822 root  cwd    DIR   0,43     4096  114 .
lsof    3823 root  cwd    DIR   0,43     4096  114 .
lsof    3824 root  cwd    DIR   0,43     4096  114 .

Comment: @Swiss_Codeaholic, yeah something werid. .not sure whats happening with you container, not sure how I would be able to help you further.